# Digestion Enzymes in Carbohydrate Metabolism?

Tags: biochemistry, digestion, carbohydrates

Digestion of carbohydrates is ending in small intestine with mainly disaccharidases. Isomaltose is broken down to 2 molecules of glucose by the enzyme called alpha dextrinase(oligo-1,6 glucosidase or isomaltase) which hydrloyze 1,6 linkage of isomaltose. In the case of glycogen metabolism there is debranching enzymes that are transferase and alpha 1,6 glucosidase. According to this informations can we say that alpha dextrinase (isomaltase) and alpha 1,6glucosidase are the same enzyme ?

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "same enzyme". Some people say "same enzyme" when they mean "same enzymatic activity" (as opposed to same protein). For example, the EC system often is said to classify enzymes, when it really classifies reactions. It's confusing :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1,6-glucosidases are a class of enzymes and not just one enzyme. It does not mean that all the members of this class are the same enzymes. They catalyse the same kind of reactions but their properties and substrate specificities differ. Check [BRENDA](http://www.brenda-enzymes.org/index.php) for details.

BTW, dextrin-1,6-glucosidase is a synonym for [amylo-alpha-1,6-glucosidase](http://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=3.2.1.33). Other 1,6-glucosidases are different enzymes with different EC numbers.